# Git-Flow and Gated Commits?

Tags: git, git-flow

We're kicking off a project and will be using the git-flow branching strategy.

However, we are trying to implement gated commits as well.

I have found info on git-flow and also on gated commits with git, but can't find anything on both together (insert non-overlapping Venn diagram here)

It seems that to have gated commits, we'll have to give up a lot of nice (automatic) behaviors in git-flow.

Has anyone implemented both of these strategies together?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply realize the gated commits pattern by using two branches. So what I suggest to you, is to succesfully apply the git-flow (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and gated commits will be unnecessary

Comment: We want to include mandatory code reviews in the gated commits.  I know I can do this (without git-flow) buy using pull requests from my feature branch to the development branch, but then I can't use the nice tooling.